# Window Service over SSL

Tags: windows, asp.net-core, https

I have an ASP.NET Core Web Hosting Project which is deployed as a Window Service. I can access it in Browser with

```
http://localhost:5000/api/...
```

My question is how can I call to this service with HTTPS, like:

```
https://localhost:5000/api/...
```

I tried to add a certificate to port 5000, using this command:

```
netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:5000 certhash=myhash appid={myappid} clientcertnegotiation=enable
```

but it didn't work, the url cannot be found. Any idea? Thanks for your help.

Comment: To verify: this is not an ASP.NET Core project?

Comment: @Gabriel: yes this is a .net core project from another team in my company. So i would like to know if there is any solution with and without touching the project's code.

Comment: Ah, ok. That is very important to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET Core projects that are hosted in a Windows Service use [Kestrel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-2.2) as the web server.

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-2.2#endpoint-configuration), Kestrel will listen on `http://localhost:5001` by default, but only "when a local development certificate is present". That's not something you would want to use for production anyway.

The only way to specify the correct certificate to use, is to [modify the code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-2.2#listenoptionsusehttps), which would look something like this (in Startup.cs):

```
.UseKestrel(options => {
    options.UseHttps(certificateFileName, certificatePassword);
}
```

If you absolutely cannot modify the code, then you will have to use a proxy. One way to do that is to use the URL Rewrite feature of IIS. Instructions are here: [Setup IIS with URL Rewrite as a reverse proxy for real world apps](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/friis/2016/08/25/setup-iis-with-url-rewrite-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-real-world-apps/)